# Deleting a subfield of a field that doesn't exist

Tags: javascript, c++, node.js

I just observed the following *weird* behavior:

### Deleting a variable that was not defined

```
> delete a
true
> delete a[0]
ReferenceError: a is not defined
> delete a.something
ReferenceError: a is not defined
> delete a.something[0]
ReferenceError: a is not defined
```

### Deleting a subfield of a field that doesn't exist

```
> a = {}
{}
> delete a.foo
true
> delete a.bar.something
TypeError: Cannot convert null to object
> a.bar
undefined
```

---

I have two questions:

- Why `delete a` works while `a` is not defined?
- Why does deleting `a.bar.something` throw the error `Cannot convert null to object` instead of `Cannot read property 'something' of undefined` (because `a.bar` is `undefined`)?

According to documentation *The `delete` operator removes a property from an object.*, so the answer for the first question would be that `a` is supposed to be a property of `this` object?

When using `delete a;` in [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) app, this error appears (and it's supposed to do) `error: ‘a’ was not declared in this scope`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The answer is split into two. The first doesn't describe much but answer the question, while the latter goes into the nitty gritty details of the specification.

### tl;dr

1. The first line works because in non-strict mode, trying to delete a variable just works.
2. The rest of the examples in the first section don't work because `a` isn't defined
3. `delete a.foo` works because there's no reason it shouldn't
4. `delete a.bar.something` throws because it's first trying to turn `a.bar` into an object before trying to access `a.bar.something`.

### And now for something completely different

First, let's make clear that the two sections of code are conceptually different since the first talks about a variable which was not declared.

We'll be looking at [how `delete` is specified](http://es5.github.io/#x11.4.1) quite a bit.

Let's start with the easier to understand parts:

```
> delete a[0]
ReferenceError: a is not defined
> delete a.something
ReferenceError: a is not defined
> delete a.something[0]
ReferenceError: a is not defined
```

All these lines are trying to do something with `a`, a variable which was not declared. Therefore, you get a `ReferenceError`. So far so good.

```
> delete a
true
```

This goes into the 3rd clause of the `delete` statement: `a` is an "unresolved reference", which is a fancy way of saying "it wasn't declared". Spec says to simply return `true` in that case.

```
> a = {}
{}
> delete a.foo
true
```

This one's intuitive as you expect (probably), but let's dive into it anyway. `delete obj.property` goes into the 4th clause:

> Return the result of calling the `[[Delete]]` internal method on `ToObject(GetBase(ref))` providing `GetReferencedName(ref)` and `IsStrictReference(ref)` as the arguments.

Welp that's a whole lot of uninteresting stuff. Let's just ignore everything after the `[[Delete]]` part, and just look at [how `[[Delete]]` is specified](http://es5.github.io/#x8.12.7). If I were to write it in js, it's be like this:

```
function Delete (obj, prop) {
    var desc = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(obj, prop);

    if (!desc) {
        return true;
    }

    if (desc.configurable) {
        desc.magicallyRemove(prop);
        return true;
    }

    throw new TypeError('trying to delete a non-configurable property, eh!?');
}
```

In the example, `a` does not have a property named `foo`, so nothing special happens.

Now it gets interesting:

```
> delete a.bar.something
TypeError: Cannot convert null to object
```

This happens because of some of the uninteresting things we ignored earlier:

> Return the result of calling the `[[Delete]]` internal method on ***`ToObject(GetBase(ref))`*** [...]

I highlighted the portion relevant to this specific snippet. Before we try to `delete` anything, spec tells us to call `ToObject(GetBase(ref))`, where `ref = a.bar.something`. Let's do that, then!

- [`GetBase`](http://es5.github.io/#GetBase)`(a.bar.something) === a.bar`
- [`ToObject`](http://es5.github.io/#x9.9)`(a.bar)` === `ToObject(undefined)` which throws a `TypeError`

Which explains the final behaviour.

Final note: The error message you've shown is misleading, since it says it tried to convert `null` into an object, which it didn't, as it tried to convert `undefined` into one. Latest chrome and firefox throw a more accurate one, but I think v8 only recently fixed the error message, so perhaps upgrading to node v11 will show a correct version.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sharing experiments and readings, hope this will help!

**1. Why delete a works while a is not defined?**

> If you try to read a property that isn’t there, JavaScript returns
>   “undefined”. This is convenient, but can mask errors if you’re not
>   careful, so watch out for typos!
>
> *Source*: http://www.w3.org/wiki/Objects_in_JavaScript

"Delete" will remove both the value and the property, so as long as JavaScript returns a value for `a`, delete will work the same way that this example:

```
var a;
delete a;
```

Besides, as you said `a` is a property of `this` object. You can see this by testing this code:

```
> var a = {}
undefined
> a
{}
> this.a
{}
```

**2. Why does deleting a.bar.something throw the error Cannot convert null to object instead of Cannot read property 'something' of undefined?**

Please look at these examples:

***NodeJS:***

```
> var a = {}
undefined
> typeof a.b
'undefined'
> typeof a.b.c
TypeError: Cannot read property 'c' of undefined
    at repl:1:12
    at ......
> delete a.b.c
TypeError: Cannot convert null to object
    at repl:1:10
    at ......
```

***Chrome console:***

```
> var a ={}
undefined
> typeof a.b
"undefined"
> typeof a.b.c
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'c' of undefined VM335:2
> delete a.b.c
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object
```

As you can see, both will manage `a.b` as an undefined value when testing `typeof`. But when deleting, chrome says that it may be `undefined` or `null`, while NodeJS consider this is a `null` value.

Would it be possible that NodeJS error is wrong formated?